# unexpected number '0.1' near '.'

Tags: lua, roblox

I'm creating a roblox game for the first time, but I got an error in my LUA code to the point where it says: unexpected number '0.1' near '.'

```
ScreenGui.Parent = game.Players.1.LocalPlayer:WaitForChild("PlayerGui")
```

I'm trying to make a GUI, but in my players folder I have a subfolder called 1, The 1 doesn't get recognized in the PATH, so my question is, how do I make it, so that the 1 gets recognized as an actual PATH/function instead of just a random integer inside the PATH/function?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use a number in combination with the index operator `.`.

Correct Lua syntax would be `ScreenGui.Parent = game.Players[1].LocalPlayer:WaitForChild("PlayerGui")`

I don't know how this is related to player folders and subfolders in Roblox. If using numbers for folder names causes problems, use other names.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response! The problem for me is that the folder "1" is imported from another game, so I can't change the name. I will try to find another way, thanks anyways!